# Count number of points and calculate the avg of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

**Hello, everybody.**

- I have to spatial files and I want to perform the count of `ordens_sort_mina`'s orders that is in `hexagonos` and then calculate the mean of the orders count inside a certain hexagon.
- **`1.`** For this very first step, I have already got a code that worked perfectly. [You can check it right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606924/count-number-of-points-in-multipolygon-shapefile-using-python)
- And this was my output for counting orders inside hexagons, using the code of link above.

| id | road_id | n | distance | geometry | count_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 159 | 72 | 1 | 0.0 | POLYGON ((-43.29064 -19.64867, -43.29058 -19.6... | 0 |
| 160 | 74 | 1 | 0.0 | POLYGON ((-43.29064 -19.64885, -43.29058 -19.6... | 0 |
| 160 | 72 | 2 | 0.0 | POLYGON ((-43.29064 -19.64885, -43.29058 -19.6... | 0 |
| 161 | 74 | 1 | 0.0 | POLYGON ((-43.29063 -19.64903, -43.29058 -19.6... | 0 |
| 161 | 72 | 2 | 0.0 | POLYGON ((-43.29063 -19.64903, -43.29058 -19.6... | 0 |

- **`2.`** What  I want to do, but still couldn't figure out is how to extract the mean of timedelta and put in the output. I have represented in `ordens_sort_mina` geodataframe a column called `difference`, that is the difference between the timestamp_orders of the row `i` minus the timestamp_orders of the row `i+1`. Basically, I want to perform the count of orders and the mean of `difference` columns of the same orders that were counted.
- This is how my `ordens_sort_mina` geodataframe is:

| order_id | priority | timestamp_orders | created_at_x | modified_at_x | geometry | id | status | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 947805c1-6631-4ed6-a4b1-cf384d5814bd | URGENTE | 2020-11-23 00:51:51 | 2020-11-23 00:51:51 | 2020-11-24 21:00:00 | POINT (-43.27593 -19.65312) | 45d72bd7-fbe4-4a94-a4ab-512cb1a3bafa | ABERTA | 38 days 08:16:18 |
| 947805c1-6631-4ed6-a4b1-cf384d5814bd | URGENTE | 2020-11-23 00:51:51 | 2020-11-23 00:51:51 | 2020-11-24 21:00:00 | POINT (-43.27593 -19.65312) | d3bf1f63-4f87-489d-9121-cf611b3bc97f | ABERTA | 0 days 00:00:00 |
| f4c84c16-590b-4dda-a9ba-043a77500dcb | MEDIA | 2020-11-23 00:51:52 | 2020-11-23 00:51:52 | 2020-11-24 21:00:00 | POINT (-43.27797 -19.65344) | 8de35981-b156-4aa4-b988-1422f4a5e36f | ABERTA | 0 days 00:00:01 |

- I tried to do a temporary_df to calculate the mean and then append to a dataframe, [just like this other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55069585/how-to-append-multiple-columns-at-the-same-time-using-panda-for-python), but it did not work.
- Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Rather than making an extensive post about your specific solution (the more specific the less likely to be useful to others), I would break it down into smaller generic questions eg how to get the mean of timedelta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616546/finding-the-mean-and-standard-deviation-of-a-timedelta-object-in-pandas-df

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I tried to explain because the last time I received a lot of downvotes and no feedbcks, so I did not know what to do. I'll edit to get more generic. Plus, this link you sent me is going to help!